# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'download' of undefined in ionic4

Tags: angular, cordova-plugins, ionic4

i'm trying to download pdf file with cordova-plugin-file-transfer but it catch the following error 
"Cannot read property 'download' of undefined"

app.module.ts imports:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
```

Providers [File,
    FileTransfer]

by console.log i checked that url is working fine but download method isn't working

```
let path = null;

if (this.plateform.is('ios')) {
  path = this.file.documentsDirectory;
} else {
  path = this.file.dataDirectory;
}

this.fileTransfer.download(url, path + 'file.pdf').then( data => {
 alert('download Complete');
```

Comment: The plugin is [deprecated](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#deprecated), you should go for [native](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html) API instead as they mention in their repo.

Comment: Even though it's deprecated it should still work (or at least it works for me in a number of apps I'm using).  The problem is that the transfer object has to be created first. See the response below

Answer (score 0):

Usage: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer#usage

```
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File) { }

...

const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

// Upload a file:
fileTransfer.upload(..).then(..).catch(..);

// Download a file:
fileTransfer.download(..).then(..).catch(..);

// Abort active transfer:
fileTransfer.abort();

// full example
upload() {
  let options: FileUploadOptions = {
     fileKey: 'file',
     fileName: 'name.jpg',
     headers: {}
     .....
  }

  fileTransfer.upload('<file path>', '<api endpoint>', options)
   .then((data) => {
     // success
   }, (err) => {
     // error
   })
}

download() {
  const url = 'http://www.example.com/file.pdf';
  fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.pdf').then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
  }, (error) => {
    // handle error
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a transfer object before using, i.e.

```
const transfer: FileTransferObject = this.fileTransfer.create();
```

```
transfer.download(url, path + 'file.pdf').then( data => {
 alert('download Complete');
```